# custom dialog error: child already has parent

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-alertdialog

I am trying to use a custom view on a Dialog. I keep getting the error

```
07-09 18:03:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(22032): java.lang.IllegalStateException:
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() 
on the child's parent first.
```

Here is my code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mine1,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.mine1));
    mine1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mine1.setView(dialoglayout);
    mine1.show();
```

How do I fix this? (Presumably all I have to do is remove view.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
if(dialoglayout.getParent()!=null){
      ((ViewGroup) dialoglayout.getParent()).removeView(dialoglayout);
}
```

You can remove view with this one.